# Blogger Free Theme - failed to remove credits

Tags: themes, blogger, blogs, blogger-dynamic-views

I have no idea about web development or writing code. However, I used my common sense to replace my domain's credits in a free blogger theme.

The attached picture shows what I exactly wrote:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs4qq.png)

And here is what the error message says:

**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3748; columnNumber: 3; The element type "div" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".**

Could someone explain **simply** how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you are missing an ending div, which means you have to sort through the code to find the opening div which does not match with a div on the same indentation level.
This can be solved with a text editor which highlights both opening and closing divs when one div is selected, thus you can see where it is missing and where to add it.
The image doesn't show enough detail to be able to resolve the issue directly for you.

Answer (score -2):

It's not that simple. Free theme developers make their themes available on condition that you keep credits to them (via their website url in the footer). Even if you delete this, there must be a snippet of code in the theme that will make your site look messy if you can't find the url that gives credit to the author. Modifying this code requires a good knowledge of HTML, CSS and Javascript.

What would you pay for a professional to analyze all the code and clean it, I think it would be more viable to buy the premium version of the theme you like.